# Explanation about the code (number of common characters from two strings)

Tags: java, arrays, string

Given two strings, find the number of common characters between them.

```
int count1[] = new int[26];
int count2[] = new int[26];
for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
    count1[s1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
}
for(int i=0;i<s2.length();i++){
    count2[s2.charAt(i) - 'a']++;

}
int common = 0;
for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
    common += Math.min(count1[i],count2[i]);
}
return common;
```

I don't understand how does it is taking the count of the common character as Math.min will always return a value and the count will keep increasing. It would be great if someone could explain to me the logic of making an alphabetic array.

Comment: Which for loops do you not understand? Just the last one? Or all 3?

Answer (score 2):

so let's take the following two strings:

```
s1 = "hello"
s2 = "locally"
```

when you initialize the two arrays, you are creating 26 indexes for each array for each letter in the alphabet. Your first for loop mutates the first array, and your second for loop mutates the second one. So let's go through the process:
During the first iteration of the first for loop, it gets the ASCII value of h (104), subtracts it from the ASCII value of a(97) and passes it as an index to the array, which is the index of the h letter in the alphabet (8th letter so index 7). it then adds 1 to that index, and it keeps iterating until the string is over.

The same process occurs for the second for loop for the second string.

For the first array, the indexes of e, h, l, and o respectively have the value of 1, 1, 2, and 1.

For the second array, the indexes of a, c, l, o, and y respectively have the value of 1, 1, 3, 1, 1

Now the third for loop iterates through both arrays at the same time, finding the minimum values in each index and adding them to count. So for example, in the first iteration, it gets the minimum between 0 and 1, which is zero. But for the iteration for l's index, it takes the minimum between 2 and 3, which is 2.

Answer (score 2):

lets say you have common character `'a'`

lets assume `'a'` occurs **2 times in the first string** and **3 times in the second string**.

in this case we have: `count1[0] = 2` and `count2[0] = 3` 
(where `0` is an index corresponding to character `'a'`)

now, `Math.min(count1[0], count2[0])` is like `Math.min(2, 3)` will return 2, which means that our strings contain 2 common characters `'a'`. This value of 2 will be added to `common` variable.

Then the loop will be repeated for other characters (b, c, d, ...) and the `common` variable will grow, accumulating the sum of all common characters

e.g. if `'b'` occurs 1 time in both strings, `common` will get 3 (as it is made of sum of 2 for `'a'` and 1 for `'b'`: 2+1=3),

and so on till we reach `'z'`, `common` will grow to the **total sum** of all common characters